# Why does my var_dump data return four times?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I need some assistance here; below is a code I have tried to work on but it is giving  me something different; When I `var_dump($price)` it gives out the values 16 times instead of 4 times and I only want the values to be given once, that is 1x4. `count($fields) == int(4)`. I also tried using just `$list_value[$row['code']]= $row;` still the same result. Below is the structure of the array and also what I have tried.

```
    fields: Array
0: Array
boxes: Array
code: amount
data_type:
error:
value: 33.00
1: Array
boxes: Array
code: quantity
data_type:
error:
value:
2: Array
boxes: Array
code: description
data_type:
error:
value: CAPTURE 
3: Array
boxes: Array
code: unit_price
data_type:
error:
value: 1.00
1:this Array
account_suggest: Array
account: Array
probabilities: Array
unmapped_accounts: Array
counter_account: Array
probabilities: Array
unmapped_accounts: Array
feature_id: 54333
fields: Array
0: Array
boxes: Array
code: unit_price
data_type:
error:
value: 1.00
1: Array
boxes: Array
code: amount
data_type:
error:
value: 125.00
2: Array
boxes: Array
code: quantity
data_type:
error:
value:
3: Array
boxes: Array
code: description
data_type:
error:
value:  MOUSE
```

```
$fields= $g['data']['line_items'];
for($i=0; $i <= count($fields); $i++){
    $lists = $g['data']['line_items'][$i]['fields'];
    foreach($lists as $key =>$row ){
        ${"list_value".$i}[$row['code']]= $row;
        $price[]= ${"list_value".$i}['unit_price']['value'];
    }
  }
    var_dump($price);
```

Comment: Its giving value 4 times because you have given $price variable as an array try removing the square brackets.

Comment: When I do that it gives only one instance of it. I mean value of price returns only one value instead of four. var_dump(count($price))==int(1). I updated the question.

Comment: You have the `var_dump()` inside the loop. Put it after the loop is done.

Comment: I updated the question..In my code it is after the loop.

Comment: Please could you add sample data for `$g['data']['line_items']`?

Comment: @Mark var_dump($g['data']['line_items'] ); == NULL.

Comment: @Vvictory not possible otherwise $fields would be null and you wouldn't enter the loop and so $price would be empty.

Comment: Exactly why I have this problem in the first place..It only has value when it is of this format $g['data']['line_items'][$i]['fields'] where $i==(any index from count($g['data']['line_items']))